# How to add an event when I click on a TextBlock?

Tags: wpf

Can I know how to add an event when I click on a TextBlock? I can't find the onClick on the TextBlock. Does anyone know what is the name of the event?

code:

```
<TextBlock Name="Title" Click="?" />
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just use the "PreviewMouseDown" event. Good luck!

Comment: Actually a click event fires when a mousedown and mouseup event both occur on the same element. That's how you're able to press down on an element and then move the mouse away and release the mouse button and not fire a click event. So in other words if you want to simulate a click event with just one event I'm thinking mouseup is closer to the real thing than mousedown.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I think then if someone clicks on a different part of the window, but releases the mouse button over the `TextBlock`, the mouseup event will fire inappropriately.

Comment: How about just using the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event of the `TextBlock`. I use this event and it works fine as a substitute for `Click` event.

Comment: Correct would be listening to the `MouseUpEvent`

Comment: Also, if you are listening to mouse clicks, you also need to listen to Keyboard events, because otherwise you can use the app with the mouse and touchpad, but not with the keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

You can use an `InputBinding`:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding